# How can I inform Sympy that L is bounded (0<L<∞)

Tags: sympy

Sometimes Sympy gives me alternate answers, that depend on assumptions on the function arguments, e.g.

```
integrate(sin(pi*x/L), (x, 0, L))

⎧         π    
⎪ 0   for ─ = 0
⎪         L    
⎨              
⎪2⋅L           
⎪───  otherwise
⎩ π
```

I know that the value `L` is positive and is limited, so that the first answer is of no relevance to me... how can I tell Sympy that `π/L` is strictly greater than zero or, as I said in the title, that `L` is bounded?

Comment: simply define `L` as `L = sympy.symbols('L', positive = True)`

Comment: @Stelios It's illogical!!! `L` is in the denominator... but it works, Why?

Comment: Good point! No clue why this is so. Generally, it is a good idea to "constrain" sympy symbol definitions as much as possible, and this is what I did, without thinking much about it. Interestingly, specifying `real=True` instead of `positive=True` does not work.

Comment: @Stelios If you want to post an answer, I'd be happy to upvote (it's useful) even if I cannot accept it... In any case, thank you

Comment: All in all, I think this is a (useful) buglet of Sympy, when I will have a bit of time I'm going to raise an issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SymPy symbols can represent infinities (`oo`, `-oo`, `zoo`) as well. Some arithmetics with these is possible. When L is infinite, pi/L is zero, so we get the integral of 0, which is zero. In this sense, SymPy's answer is correct. If L is meant to be finite, declaring it as such with

```
L = symbols("L", finite=True)
```

is enough to get `2*L/pi` as an answer.

Or you can leave L as is and tell SymPy to not worry about the edge cases with `conds="none"` parameter of the integration.

```
integrate(sin(pi*x/L), (x, 0, L), conds="none")   # 2*L/pi
```

---

Aside: `real=True` does not exclude the possibility of L being  `oo`  or `-oo`, as these are considered real: `oo.is_real` is True (this is a contentious point in SymPy development).

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do you have a reference for all the constraints that you can put on a symbol?  I had a look before asking but I couldn't find `finite=True` ... as an aside, why does `positive=True` work?

Comment: The list of assumptions is [here](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/core.html#module-sympy.core.assumptions). I don't know why `positive=True` makes SymPy discard the `L=oo` case here, because it should not.